# Laptop dedicated GPU - performace drop / variable performance

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, power-supply, battery, gpu

Laptop GPUs (dedicated and integrated) are driving me crazy ever since I got this computer. I've searched thousands of forums and potential solutions and I couldn't find anything that solves my problem.

Main problem I guess is the dedicated GPU (GeForce 840M) which I swear has an attitude of its own! It sometimes runs a game on 40fps or more but sometimes 20fps or less for the same one I played an hour before with no problem! The problem timeline goes something like this:

**1.** Start playing/using with AC plugged and no battery (I noticed that without the battery it runs much better). Game runs smoothly.

**2.** I connect the battery and start using it for other things, unplugged.

**3.** Connect it to AC (sometimes just 5mins later) and the GPUs performance is just awful. Just to test it I overloaded it as much as I can but no sign came neither from temperature increase (around 57c max) or Clockage.

**4.** I use *GPU-z* and can notice large drops in GPU Core Clock (when im using the game) and smaller drops in Voltage. Temperature is not an issue, 65c-68c when working fine (as in no problems with gpu) but when the problem appears it doesn't go over 55c.

Main problem is that if I shut it down and start it without battery, it sometimes may again struggle (hence the attitude problem). When I hear the fan kicking in and it starts to make noise I feel relieved.

I've tried allot of solutions - power options, switchable graphics settings, driver reinstallation (clean), driver roll back, etc.

PS - I've noticed an annoying thing regarding battery and AC performance, as soon as I unplug the AC the screen dims a bit, but my power setting is always set to maximum performance.

Answer (score 0):

Download MSI Afterburner to manually overclock/improve your GPU performance.
Your GPU maker **should** have a program dedicated to settings, just like on mine it is AMD Catalyst Control Center

Comment: I tried that. Overclocking doesnt improve performance but only leads in BSOD at some points. I dont like the idea of overclocking in any way a laptop gpu. Besides I would have to overclock everytime i turn on my computer because it resets the values...

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the end I decided to clean install windows 10. And actualy that solved my problem and some other also. I dont know if reinstalling windows 8.1, which I was running before, would help but I think the **solution is clean installation/reinstallation of OS**.